# SSL Offloading on kubernetes ingress not working with Magnolia

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, magnolia, offloading

Im currently trying to deploy a magnolia instance, running in kubernetes.
We want to SSL offload on ingress level, but apparently we have some issues, with the login to Magnolia UI. If we are not using an ingress, it just works fine. 
I assume, that in the SSL-offloading approach, the X-Forwarded-header gets ignored by Magnolia.

- Is this statement true ?
- Is there some way to workaround this ?
- Any one got this issue, or is running an ingressed kubernetes with magnolia stable?

I've looked through the various filters, especially the LoginFilter, but cant find the spot, where the actual response is build up and send back to client.
Is it possible, that the redirect (we use POST to login) ignores https, as Magnolia isnt aware of that we talk to magnolia via https, due to the offloading ?
In Magnolia I have checked the http-headers, and all headers (x-forwarded-*) are set correctly..

Comment: What’s app server on which you are running Magnolia? Look for solution in setting of app server. Magnolia doesn’t do anything special with protocol or certificate.

Comment: the `proxy_redirect` directive was set to off in nginx, replacing this with `proxy_redirect http:// $https_scheme://;` fixed my issue